# How to execute Zeo Decoder Viewer on Linux?

Tags: java

I'm trying to execute [Zeo Decoder Viewer](http://zeodecoderview.sourceforge.net/) (a Java application) on Linux, and I'm not sure how I'm supposed to do this.

I've put the program and required libraries (all in jar files) in /opt/zeo/ directory, and I try this:

```
miernik@przehyba:/opt/zeo$ ls
appframework-1.0.3.jar  joda-time-1.6.jar  swing-worker-1.1.jar  ZeoDecoderViewer.jar
miernik@przehyba:/opt/zeo$ java -jar ZeoDecoderViewer.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdesktop/application/SingleFrameApplication
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        ... 12 more
Could not find the main class: com.myzeo.viewer.ZeoDecoderViewer. Program will exit.
miernik@przehyba:/opt/zeo$
```

Am I doing something basic horribly wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally the answer would involve classpaths and the `-cp` argument, but the [documentation](http://zeodecoderview.sourceforge.net/starting.html) for this particular project makes the issue clear:

> Extract the jar file and lib folder to
>   a directory of your choosing.

Those other three jars are expected to be in a subfolder called `lib`, not in the same directory as the "main" jar.